# How to get the last event fired on ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, error-handling, event-listener, extjs6

I'm trying to create a costume Error handler. So far I'm able to retrieve the errors triggered by the system with the following code:

```
window.onerror = function(message, source, lineno, colno, error) {
             me.errorHandler(error, true);
             return true;
        };
```

My problem is: I would love to specify what kind of event or action triggered my error.

Is there any way to find out what Events/Listeners/Actions were triggered? Something like using Ext.util.Observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my solution.
Its something like this;

```
    //object is the main Page/Menu that i want to "Observate"
    Ext.util.Observable.capture(object, function(){
        //arguments have the listener, page and component
        doStuff(arguments)
        });
```

Doing this, every time an event is fired on the "object" this function will be triggered, and i can log the error or the event fired.